# Query for finding a users rank in game database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Currently have the following information in game table

```
ID       Name       XP
1        Bob        11
2        Jim        120
3        Dan        56
4        Oli        32
```

I want find the rank when pulling a single user for example. I want to be able to Pull 'Jim' as rank number 1 and 'Bob' as rank number 4 for example.

I had this query but it seems very messed up.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+2 FROM game WHERE xp > (SELECT xp FROM game WHERE id = '$id')
```

Comment: Your query seems right but why `+2` and not `+1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT g1.id, COUNT(DISTINCT g2.XP)+1 rank
FROM
  game g1 LEFT JOIN game g2
  ON g1.XP < g2.XP
GROUP BY
  g1.id
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fc54/6). You could use DISTINCT or not, depending on what you are after.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You'll want an INDEX on XP.

Comment: I was making a silly mistake - This works perfect, Will accept when i can :)

Comment: Make sure you accept his answer when you can so that others finding this entry know that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to populate an array for finding their "rank". If you simply want the highest:

```
"SELECT * FROM game WHERE xp = MAX(xp)"
```

If you want a table ordered by their rank in xp I would suggest populating an array with the data so you can sort it by xp and then deliver it accordingly. I also use a $db class in my scripts, but it should make sense:

```
while($data = $db->sql_query("SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY xp DESC"){
    $rank++;
    $users[]['name'] = $data['name'];
    $users[]['xp'] = $data['xp'];
    $users[]['rank'] = $rank;
}

echo '<table><tr><td>Rank</td><td>Name</td><td>XP</td></tr>';

foreach($users as $user){
     echo'<tr><td>'.$user['rank'].'</td><td>'.$user['name'].'</td><td>'.$user['xp'].'</td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

In my experience it has always been easier to cope with the information if you just populate an array. There might be some tricks in sql query syntax I am missing, but it gets the job done.